# Reg exp match if exists

Tags: regex

How can I write a reg exp to do:

```
"SomeString" # Match the string
`SomeString Bonus_string" # Match "SomeString" AND "Bonus_string"
```

Basically I want to match a string if it exists, but if it doesn't exist still match the other ones...

I'm hoping it's just one small change. Here is my progress so far: http://rubular.com/r/4YRagwSuTN

For reference: `(.+)(?:| .+)`

I have a feeling I have to put a `*` in somewhere..

Comment: Please don't point to outside sites to show your code.  The questions you ask on SO are here forever, and the outside links are not.  Please paste the code in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out...

```
(\w+)( \w+)*
```

http://rubular.com/r/VSRDMrOYlN